# Hex dump parsing in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, hexdump

I have a hex dump of a message in a file which i want to get it in an array
so i can perform the decoding logic on it.
I was wondering if that was a easier way to parse a message which looks like this.

> 37 39 30 35 32 34 35 34 3B 32 31 36 39 33 34 35
>   3B 32 31 36 39 33 34 36 00 00 01 08 40 00 00 15
>   6C 71 34 34 73 69 6D 31 5F 33 30 33 31 00 00 00
>   00 00 01 28 40 00 00 15 74 65 6C 63 6F 72 64 69
>   74 65 6C 63 6F 72 64 69

Note that the data can be max 16 bytes on any row. But any row can contain fewer bytes too (minimum :1 )
Is there a nice and elegant way rather than to read 2 chars at a time in perl ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has a [`hex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) operator that performs the decoding logic for you.

> #### `hex EXPR`
>
> #### `hex`
>
> Interprets EXPR as a hex string and returns the corresponding value. (To convert strings that might start with either `0`, `0x`, or `0b`, see [`oct`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html).) If EXPR is omitted, uses `$_`.
>
> ```
> print hex '0xAf'; # prints '175'
> print hex 'aF'; # same
> ```

Remember that the default behavior of [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) chops up a string at whitespace separators, so for example

```
$ perl -le '$_ = "a b c"; print for split'
a
b
c
```

For every line of the input, separate it into hex values, convert the values to numbers, and [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) them onto an array for later processing.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @values;
while (<>) {
  push @values => map hex($_), split;
}

# for example
my $sum = 0;
$sum += $_ for @values;
print $sum, "\n";
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./sumhex mtanish-input 
4196
```

Answer (score 6):

I would read a line at a time, strip the whitespace, and use `pack 'H*'` to convert it.  It's hard to be more specific without knowing what kind of "decoding logic" you're trying to apply.  For example, here's a version that converts each byte to decimal:

```
while (<>) {
  s/\s+//g;
  my @bytes = unpack('C*', pack('H*', $_));
  print "@bytes\n";
}
```

Output from your sample file:

```
55 57 48 53 50 52 53 52 59 50 49 54 57 51 52 53
59 50 49 54 57 51 52 54 0 0 1 8 64 0 0 21
108 113 52 52 115 105 109 49 95 51 48 51 49 0 0 0
0 0 1 40 64 0 0 21 116 101 108 99 111 114 100 105
116 101 108 99 111 114 100 105
```

Answer (score 0):

I think reading in two characters at a time is the appropriate way to parse a stream whose logical tokens are two-character units.

Is there some reason you think that's ugly?

If you're trying to extract a particular sequence, you could do that with whitespace-insensitive regular expressions.